# System.in.read() - why two empty lines after Carriage Return?

Tags: java, inputstream

I searched a lot, but I did not find an accurate answer.

Why does my program puts out an extra line (so two empty lines) after reading out my carriageReturn?

When I finish the while loop before the carriageReturn (13) it prints "------" directly after "c".

Here is my programm:

```
import java.io.*;
class IOIntro {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
     int letter = 0;
    System.out.print("Type a letter and press Enter: ");

   while((letter = System.in.read ()) !=10) { //loops throw whole inputStream until there is a new Line Feed
       System.out.println("You typed: " + letter);
       System.out.println((char) letter);
    }
   System.out.print("--------");
   }
 }
```

Output after 13(Carriage Return), before 10 (Line Feed) :

```
Type a letter and press Enter: ads
You typed: 97
a
You typed: 100
d
You typed: 115
s
You typed: 13


--------
```

Output before 13 (Carriage Return):

```
Type a letter and press Enter: ads
You typed: 97
a
You typed: 100
d
You typed: 115
s
--------
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Because you're printing a newline, then `println` finishes the line with a newline.

Comment: Thank you! Got it!

Comment: Note that this only happens on windows, or other platforms which use `\r\n` as the newline separator. Check [this demo](http://ideone.com/tig9NS), which demonstrates it for both `\n`- and `\r\n`-style newlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe this line:

```
System.out.println((char) letter);
```

You are printing the letter with ASCII-code `13` which stands for "carriage return". Plus you are using `println` which prints an extra new line at the end of its input. So two empty lines are printed to the console.

> Update:

The `Enter` key a.k.a. `Return` key sends a `\r` or character code `13` to the console. So, in your `while` loop condition, make this change:

```
while((letter = System.in.read ()) != '\r') {
```

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: 13 is carriage return. 10 is new line.

Comment: Corrected it. Thanks!

Comment: Why would printing a carriage return print a newline, though? They're not the same thing.

Comment: I think the console cannot go back to the beginning of the same line. The only way for it to go back to the beginning of the line is to go to the next line.

Comment: Thank you! That helped. So my understanding of "Curriage Return" was not right ;)

Comment: Carraige Return (CR) Ideally takes your cursor to the beginning of the "current" line. A Line Feed (LF) will take your cursor to the next line keeping the cursor right below where it was on the previous line. Thus, a New Line is achieved by a combination of CR+LF.

Comment: @anacron "achieved by a combination of CR+LF" on windows. On *nix, it's just a LF.

Comment: @anacron but in my case the "10" / "\n" is the codition to end the loop. So it does not print LF.

Comment: @AndyTurner, Correct. I don't have a *nix box to try it out right now. Must see how the program works on non-Windows system.

Comment: @anacron: I understand your updated answer, but this was not the question. Wenn I put  `13` or `\r` into the condition it finishes the programm after `s` in this case. But when I finish the programm after the carriage return it prints an extra line. Carriage Return only puts the corsor to the beginning of the line I thought.  Interesting Topic.

Comment: Each system uses its own New Line Character. It could be a combination of CR+LF, LF+CR or just CR. Use `System.lineSeparator()` to find out what new line character or string is used by your system. On mine I see CR+LF (13+10)

Comment: You can even try this: `while ((letter = System.in.read()) != System.lineSeparator().charAt(0)) {`         Platform Independence!

Comment: @anacron How to print out System.lineSeparator()  ? ;) When I put it in an System.out.print(), it makes a new line. ("Microsoft Windows systems it returns "\r\n".")

Comment: What you see is correct. `\r\n` is what Windows considers new line. So when you use `System.out.print(System.lineSeparator());` on Windows, you will see `\r\n`. When you use the same code on a Mac or other systems, you will see a different character: only `\n` or `\r` or even `\n\r`. If you want to see that in Windows, Create a text file in notepad, type in a couple of characters and hit enter. Open the file in a Hex editor, you'll see `0D 0A` characters which stand for `\r\n`.

Answer (score 0):

When you press Enter, on Windows you get two characters back: a carriage return (13) and a line feed (10).

The code 13 is somewhat confusing because on some platforms (e.g. OSX) it means *new line*.

Your IDE is probably trying to play it safe and is interpreting it as newline. If you're using Eclipse, see [bug 76936](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=76936)

`\r` (13) should move the cursor to the beginning of the line, but *stay on that line*.

If you run your application in a true console, you should see only one newline.

```
>java -cp . IOIntro
Type a letter and press Enter:
You typed: 13

--------
>
```

---

If you want to silently exit on Enter, change your test from `10` to `13`:

```
   while((letter = System.in.read ()) !=13) {
       System.out.println("You typed: " + letter);
       System.out.println((char) letter);
    }
```

Comment: 13 is carriage return. 10 is new line.

Answer (score 0):

13 is a carriage return, and `println()` writes a newline.

So:

```
 System.out.println("You typed: " + letter);
 System.out.println((char) letter);
```

For 'a', prints:

```
 Your typed: 100{newline}a{newline}
```

For '{newline}', prints:

```
 You typed: 13{newline}{cr}{newline}
```

... which is what you see.